# Update Bokeh figure

Tags: python, bokeh

Inside a Jupyter Notebook I draw 3 circles.

```
fig = figure(plot_width = 300, plot_height = 300)
fig.circle(x = [1, 2, 3], y = [3, 7, 5], size = 20, color ="green", alpha = 0.6)
show(fig)
```

I would like to change one circle color I can do:

```
fig.circle(x = 2, y = 7, size = 20, color ="blue", alpha = 0.6)
show(fig)
```

Let say I have thousand circles. I don't want to redraw all the circles, only one of them.
Is there a way to update the figure without using show ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass single values to `color` as you did. But `color` does also accepts lists or names of a `ColumnDataSource`.

```
fig = figure(plot_width = 300, plot_height = 300)
fig.circle(
    x = [1, 2, 3],
    y = [3, 7, 5],
    size = 20,
    color = ["green", "blue", "green"],
   alpha = 0.6
)
show(fig)
```

With a `CustomJS` you can update your `ColumnDataSource` without calling `show` again. See [this section about js callbacks](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/js_callbacks.html) to get a impression on how to creat interactive figures.

### Minimal working Example

Below is an example where to widgets are used to change the colors of the circles.

```
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import TextInput, Slider, ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

data = dict(
    x = [1, 2, 3],
    y = [3, 7, 5],
    color = ["green", "blue", "green"],
)
source = ColumnDataSource(data)

fig = figure(width = 300, height = 300)
fig.circle(
    x = 'x',
    y = 'y',
    size = 20,
    color = 'color',
    source=source,
    alpha = 0.6
)

textinput = TextInput(value="")
slider = Slider(
    value=0,
    start=0,
    end=len(data['x'])-1,
    step=1,
    width=100
)

callback = CustomJS(
    args=dict(slider=slider, source=source, textinput=textinput),
    code="""
    var color = source.data['color'];
    color[slider.value] = cb_obj.value;
    source.change.emit();
"""
)
textinput.js_on_change("value", callback)

show(column(row(textinput, slider), fig))
```

### Output

[image: change color by position and input]

Comment: Ok thanks I know that JS can do the job I was wondering if it was possible using a python bokeh trick ...

Comment: Thanks  .
I`s there a way to make such color selection using python command ?
python command to inject some JavaScript command to replace the Slider and TextInput ?

Comment: It is possible to use [python callbacks](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/python_callbacks.html) with a server. It is very close to the linked section about js-callbacks. Please read the documentation, because I have no experiance with this kind of callbacks.

Comment: You mentioned JupyterNotebooks and as far as I know it is not possible to use python callbacks in a Notebook.